# Image of a function

Tags: real-analysis

I have a solution to a problem here which I don't understand. The task is to find the image of this beauty:

$$ y=f(x)=\frac{1+x}{1+x^2}$$

We can rewrite this to:

$$yx^2-x+y-1=0.$$

For y=0 this solves to x=-1. Now we look at y=! 0 and this is where things get murky.

We get:

$$x^2-\frac xy+1-\frac1y=0$$
This can be solved when:

$$ \Delta:=\frac1{y^2}-4\left(1-\frac1y\right)=-\frac{4y^2-4y-1}{y^2}\geq0$$

(... How? What? Why? Where does all this come from?)

Thus when we have:
$$ 4y^2-4y-1\leq0$$

Finally, we get:
$$\left\{y\in\mathbf{R}:|2y-1|\leq\sqrt2\right\}=
\left\{y\in\mathbf{R}:2y\in\left[1-\sqrt2,1+\sqrt2\right]\right\}
=\left\lfloor-\frac{\sqrt2-1}2,\frac{\sqrt2+1}2\right\rfloor,$$
Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: The $\Delta$ term is the discriminant in the quadratic equation when solving $x^2 - \frac 1 y x + \left(1-\frac 1y\right)$.

Comment: $\Delta=-((2y-1)^2-2)/y^2$. It is therefore positive only when $|2y-1|<\sqrt2$. If $\Delta<0$, there is no $x$ corresponding to the value of $y$. If $\Delta=0$ there is only one solution $x$ and if $\Delta>0$, there are two distinct solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$.

The graph of the function $y=f(x)$ lies in the stripe that you have computed. Every horizontal line in this stripe defined by its ordinate $y$ crosses the graph of $f$ twice except if $y=0$, $y=-(\sqrt2-1)/2$ or $y=(\sqrt2+1)/2$ in which cases there is only one crossing. The two latter cases correspond to the extrema of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that [the discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant) of an quadratic equation
$$ax^2+bx+c=0$$
is represented as
$$b^2-4ac.$$

In your case, when $y\not=0$, 
$$x^2-\frac xy+1-\frac 1y=0$$
has to have *at least one real solution* $x$. (why?)

It is known that a quadratic equation has *at least one real solution* if and only if the discriminant is $0$ or larger than $0$.

So, you'll get an inequality
$$\left(-\frac 1y\right)^2-4\cdot 1\cdot \left(1-\frac 1y\right)\ge0\iff \frac{1}{y^2}-4\left(1-\frac 1y\right)\ge0.$$